# Server is not displaying the message got from client in the text widget made using Tkinter

Tags: python

It is not displaying he text send by the client and the message send by the client is expected to be displayed in the text box made but it is not displaying.
Please help me doing this.The question is  basically how it will display the text received form client to the text widget in the server.

```
import socket
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 40025 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

# Datagram (udp) socket
try :
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print 'Socket created'
except socket.error, msg :
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

def talk():

#now keep talking with the client
  while 1:
    # receive data from client (data, addr)
    d = s.recvfrom(1024)
    text_area.insert(END,'Client:+'+d+'\n')
    data = d[0]
    addr = d[1]

    if not data: 
        break

    reply = 'OK...' + data

    s.sendto(reply , addr)
    text_area.insert(END,'Server:'+reply+'\n')
    print 'Message[' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]) + '] - ' + data.strip()
    s.blocking(0)
    mainloop()



root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
root.geometry("500x500")
text_area = Text(frame)
text_area.pack(side=BOTTOM)
talk()














root.mainloop()
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have either two or three different infinite loops, which pretty much guarantees your program isn't going to work right. I don't know what that one call to `mainloop()` is -- is that where you're attempting to call `root.mainloop()` but have a typo?

If you have a tkinter program, you must call the `mainloop` function of the root window exactly once, and you should have no other infinite loops running. You can poll a socket pretty easily with `after`, or you can use separate threads. What you can't do is put an infinite loop inside your GUI code.

Comment: so what is the solution to this problem dude.